# Selecting 1 side of an edge loop in a mesh

Tags: selection-tools, knife-tool

[image: my first img]

Hi, I created an edge loop by knife tool on this model (with K , then Z shortcuts in edit mode).

Now, how can I select all the vertices only right or left side of it (selected vertices will be included as well) ? Thanks in advance.

I also added my blender file here : [image]

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't have any other vertices hidden you can **hide** (<kbd>H</kbd>) the edge loop to have to separate parts of the object in edit mode.

Then you can select one of the separate parts by using **select linked** (<kbd>L</kbd>).

After that you can **reveal** (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) the hidden vertices which are then selected automatically.

Now you have everything to the right or left from the edge loop selected!

In this example the right side of the edge loop plus the edge loop itself are selected.

[image: Example of the process]

Note that if the part left and right of the edge loop are connected somewhere else this method won't work unless you hide the other connection as well (e.g. a torus).

Comment: Sorry , I andwered so late but still that didn't solve my problem. I can select them as you said after hiding them but when I unhide them new faces (that are related to the hided vertices) still seems unselected.

Comment: I also added my blend file to my question and that's my aim: drawing a line that cuts left arm of model and choosing all the faces towards the left hand from that line (including new faces that are creted with this line) and lastly seerate it from the object.

Comment: Lastly, I noticed that my problem is related to your 'note' section thank you though:)